# Passing a string with double quotations as parameter from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to figure this thing out and I don't know what I'm doing wrong or maybe I'm missing something.

I'm trying to pass a string which contains double quotes that I retrieved from my database to be displayed in a `textarea`.

Situation sample looks like this:

```
<?php
   $content = '<div align="center"><b>This is a sample content.</b></div>';
   echo '<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>';
   echo '<button onclick="myFunction('.$content.')">Click me</button>';
?>

<script>
  function myFunction(content){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML = content;
  }
</script>
```

Expected results should be that *myTextArea* should contain the text, but the result shows:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5gyz.jpg)

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this `$content = '<div align="center"><b>This is a sample content.</b></div>';`

Comment: that was a typo on my part but output stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote your output using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)(), such that it reads:

```
<?php
   $content = "<div align=\"center\"><b>This is a sample content.</b></div>";
   echo '<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>';
   echo '<button onclick="myFunction(\''.htmlspecialchars($content).'\')">Click me</button>';
?>

<script>
  function myFunction(content){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML = content;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes inside the string:

```
   $content = "<div align=\"center\"><b>This is a sample content.</b></div>";
```

You could also use apostrophes in this case, like

```
   $content = "<div align='center'><b>This is a sample content.</b></div>";
```

or

```
   $content = '<div align="center"><b>This is a sample content.</b></div>';
```

EDIT:

Also, make sure you use content as a string:

```
echo '<button onclick="myFunction(\''.$content.'\')">Click me</button>';
```